# Plotting partially aggregated data with percentages (dot or scatter plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following crime data (number of crimes for three years grouped by the type of crime):

```r
df <- data.frame(crime = c("theft", "theft", "theft", "burglary", "burglary", "burglary", "rape", "rape", "rape"),
                 year = as.factor(rep(c(2017, 2018, 2019), 3)),
                 number = c(100, 110, 80, 70, 62, 30, 10, 12, 18))
df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(crime), y = number, color=year, pch=year))+geom_point() + 
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Crime") +
  ylab("Number of crimes")
```

This code works fine, but now I'd like to create a similar plot with two dots instead of three for each year. One point should be the average value 2017 and 2018 (= 100%) and the second point should represent
the percentage of the value of 2019.

```
         |
theft    | ---------- x ------  o ----------------   x = 2019
         |                                           o = avg(2017, 2018)
burglary |------------ x ------ o ----------------
         |
rape     | -------------------- o ----- x -------- 
         |
         |________________________________________
                   50%        100%      150%
```

Unfortunately after playing around for quite some time I have no idea, how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: btw how did you produce this console style graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest to create a summary of your data outside ggplot. 
I've also added some modifications to your code, also to combine shape and color legend. You can remove that if you don't like that.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mydf <- data.frame(crime = c("theft", "theft", "theft", "burglary", "burglary", "burglary", "rape", "rape", "rape"),
           year = as.factor(rep(c(2017, 2018, 2019), 3)),
           number = c(100, 110, 80, 70, 62, 30, 10, 12, 18))
mydf %>% 
  group_by(crime, year = year!=2019) %>%
  summarise(mean_nbr= mean(number)) %>%
  group_by(crime) %>%
  mutate(perc = 100* mean_nbr/ mean_nbr[year]) %>%

ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(crime), y = perc, color=year, shape=year))+
  geom_point() + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_shape_discrete(labels = c(`FALSE` = "2017/2018", `TRUE`= "2019")) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Accent", labels = c(`FALSE` = "2017/2018", `TRUE`= "2019")) +
  labs(x = "Crime", y = "Number of crimes") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(), shape = guide_legend())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>